# Responsive bootstrap nav with brand

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble keeping my navbar responsive.  When the browser reaches a certain size, the height will increase. I made a fiddle to show what is happening, if you expand the preview, the navbar will be normal.

http://jsfiddle.net/x70r23cn/

```
  .navbar {
    background-color: #204489;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    float: center;
  }
  .navbar a {
    color: #fff;
  }

  .navbar-brand img  {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 25px;
  }
  .navbar-brand {
      margin-left: auto !important;
      margin-right: auto !important;
      display: block !important;
      float: none !important;
  }

  <nav class='navbar navbar-fixed-top'>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='navbar-header'>
        <button aria-controls='navbar' aria-expanded='false' class='navbar-toggle collapsed' data-target='#navbar' data-toggle='collapse' type='button'>
          <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class='navbar-brand'>
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=271&h=25" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Are placing anything else inside the navbar of just the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `navbar-header` class as it's designed to enable the collapse menu on mobile devices; that's why the navbar is expanding.

See example Snippet.

```css
.navbar.navbar-custom {
  background-color: #204489;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  float: center;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom a {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  float: none;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-brand img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 25px;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class='navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='navbar-brand'>
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=271&h=25" />
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this... the `navbar-brand` needs to be in the `navbar-header` and the `navbar-brand` needs to be `inline` or `inline-block`.

```css
.navbar {
    background-color: #204489;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    float: center;
}
.navbar a {
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-brand img  {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 25px;
}
.navbar-brand {
      margin-left: auto !important;
      margin-right: auto !important;
      display: block !important;
      float: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
                <span class="sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand">
                <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=271&h=25" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
<nav>
```